# add data to the end of a behavior object array Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data that I want to be shared with my entire app so I have created a service like so..

**user.service**

```
userDataSource = BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);

userData = this.userDataSource.asObservable();

updateUserData(data) {
    this.userDataSource.next(data);
}
```

then in my component Im getting some data from an api and then sending that data to `userDataSource` like so..

```
constructor(
private: userService: UserService,
private: api: Api
){
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getData()
      .subscribe((data) => { 
         this.userService.updateUserData(data);
      })
}
```

now that all works but.. I want to be able to add data to the end of the array inside the `userDataSource` so basically the equivalent of a `.push` am I able to just call the `updateUserData()` function and add more data or will doing that overwrite what is currently in there?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can add a new method to your service like `addData` in which you can combine your previous data with new data like.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable() 
export class UserService {
    userDataSource: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    userData = this.userDataSource.asObservable();

    updateUserData(data) {
        this.userDataSource.next(data);
    }

    addData(dataObj) {
        const currentValue = this.userDataSource.value;
        const updatedValue = [...currentValue, dataObj];
        this.userDataSource.next(updatedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved me an hour quest with this. In the end, I have condesed it like this:
`this.userDataSource$.next([...this.userDataSource$.value, dataObj]);`

Answer (score 8):

For someone that may come accross this issue with a `BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]>`.

I found [in this article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services) a way to properly add the new array of `YourObject`

```js
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { YourObject} from './location';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ObjService {
    private theObjData: BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]>(null);

    constructor() {
    }

    public SetObjData(newValue: YourObject[]): void {
        this.theObjData.next(Object.assign([], newValue));
    }
}
```

How to update data:

```js
// inside some component
this.api.userData().subscribe((results:YourObject) => 
    this.objService.SetObjData(results);
)
```

How to observe changes on other component

```js
// inside another component
ngOnInit() {
    this.objService.GetAccountStatements().subscribe((results) =>
    ...
    )
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me `private theObjData: BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]>(null);` so i had to change it to `private theObjData: BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<YourObject[]>([]);` the problem was the **null**

Comment: Object.assign([], newValue) - tego potrzebowałam, dzięki wilekie !!

Answer (score 3):

Normally `Observables` and `Subject`s are meant to be *streams* of data, not an assignment of data. `BehaviorSubject`s are different because they hold their last emitted value.

Normally `Subject`s or `BehaviorSubjects` inside of a contained class (like a Service) do not want to expose themselves publicly to any other classes, so it's best practice to access their properties with `get`ters or methods. This keeps the data stream cold to all subscribers.

However, since the `BehaviorSubject` holds the last emitted value, there's a few options here. If *all* subscribers need a concatenated stream of data from every emission, you could access the last emitted value and append to it:

```
userDataSource = BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

userData = this.userDataSource.asObservable();

updateUserData(data) {

    this.userDataSource.next(this.userDataSource.value.push(data));
}
```

...or, in what might be considered better practice, Subscribers to this Subject could do their own transformation on the stream:

```
this.api.userData()
  .scan((prev, current) => prev.push(current). [])
  .subscribe((data) => { 
     this.concatenatedUserData = data;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use concat to add object

```
userDataSource = BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);

updateUserData(data) {
    this.userDataSource.next(this.userDataSource.value.concat(data));
}
```

Use filter to remove object

```
removeUserData(data) {
    this.userDataSource.next(this.userDataSource.value.filter(obj => obj !== data));
}
```