# declare service variable as array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to declare this user as an array

```
users = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
```

in my component i'm trying to push the userID

```
this.Service.users.push(userID);
```

subscribe it like this

```
 this.Service.users.subscribe(x=>{
      
 });
```

getting

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add data to the end of a behavior object array Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525637/add-data-to-the-end-of-a-behavior-object-array-angular-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `this.Service.users` is not an `Array` but `BehaviorSubject<any>`.

You should do something like this:

```
// get copy of current value
cosnt value = this.Service.users.value.concat();
// append new userId
value.push(userId);
// emit
this.Service.users.next(value);
```